# Quelle est la nature de l'apport de l'argot au sens du mot « froc » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, argot, registre-familier, lexique

Le [*froc*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/froc) (n. m.) c'est à l'origine, hormis une attestation isolée pour le « manteau »(DHLF/Rey), d'un francique *hrokk* etc. et c'est d'abord au 12<sup>e</sup> le « vêtement de moine qui couvre la tête et les épaules » (TLFi) et la poitrine (DHLF/Rey). Il faudra plusieurs siècles pour qu'il y ait l'extension à l'habit monacal tout entier au 17<sup>e</sup>. Puis, au tout début du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle, et d'abord en argot, on a le sens de « culotte » ou « pantalon » <sup>1</sup> qu'on dit populaire aujourd'hui, où l'on ne réfère plus qu'au *pantalon* ([Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/froc/35346?q=froc#35313), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/froc)).

---

- Peut-on expliquer et détailler l'apport particulier de l'argot au sens
  de « pantalon » : quel argot, d'où, pourquoi dans le sens du vêtement
  du bas du corps et non dans le sens du manteau ; l'apport est-il
  typique, ressemble-t-il à d'autres altérations de sens d'autres mots
  (des vêtements ?) de cette époque par l'argot qui sont simplement
  populaires aujourd'hui et comment qualifie-t-on cette influence de
  l'argot au lexique ?
- Le sens de « culotte » dont il était question a-t-il eu un quelconque
  lien avec le sens de « caleçon » ou était-ce simplement une autre
  manière de dire « pantalon » ?
- Dans la vie de tous les jour aujourd'hui (hormis au Qc., voir
  *Wiktionnaire*, nom commun f. 2), *froc* seul dans une phrase quelconque peut-il vouloir dire autre chose que *pantalon* ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On réfère à des dates bien précises dont, en particulier 1905 : "1905 « culotte » (d’après Esnault, [sans doute son *Dictionnaire des argots français*].); b) 1912 « pantalon » (d'apr. ibid.)" (TLFi) ; 1905 « culotte » ou « pantalon », 1917 pour une locution comme *baisser son froc* (DHLF/Rey).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Sans valeur autre que de commentaire :

A/ Quelle est cette *"nature"* que vous attendez être *"de l'apport de l'argot au sens"* ?

Formulée ainsi et ici, cette question ne peut obtenir qu'une seule réponse : Sémantique! L'apport de l'argot au sens de *froc* est de nature : sémantique! Périod!

B/ Comme le langage des Schtroumpfs, l'argot est un langage dit *parasitaire*. (No disrespect meant) => Conformément à ceux qui le partiquent<sup>1</sup>... il pique... plus qu'il ne refile au langage commun. Et si... par mégarde... il venait à être compris du commun... : Il change!

C/ L'apport de l'argot à la langue commune est donc plus généralement essentiellement de nature lexicale. La langue commune emprunte donc à l'argot un mot avec son sens (plus ou moins supposé)

D/ L'argot fabrique donc un mot authentique à partir d'un mot piqué à une langue vivante. (Il n'a évidemment pas piqué le froc au francique...) le transforme éventuellement et... lui confère un sens caché. Et, dans cette intention, nécessairement différent de ce lui entendu dans la langue commune.

E/ Il s'ensuit que si, d'aventure, la langue commune récupère ce mot avec sa signification particulière, c'est son lexique qui va s'enrichir. Et, si le mot n'a pas été transformé, le lexique va donc s'enrichir d'un : **homonyme**.

La langue commune n'a donc plus un seul mot froc désignant exclusivement l'habit des moines mais deux. Le précédent et l'argotique désignant le pantalon. En ce sens, l'argot n'a pas enrichi le sens de *froc*, il a juste enrichi le lexique d'un... homonyme.

<sub>1 : Je parle ici de l'argot au sens *étroit*, tel qu'entendu par Littré et surtout : **Dauzat**. *Votre* Esnault (qui leur est postérieur) entendant plus largement l'argot au sens d'ensemble oral de mots qui plaisent à un groupe social.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

La nature argotique du mot est arrivée avec sa réutilisation de nos jours, notamment parce qu'il est associé à des expressions comme "baisser son froc", "pisser/chier dans son froc", qui définissent une humiliation dans un registre familier.

Et puisque c'est un héritage lié aux moines, je pense qu'il est associé de nos jour au pantalon qui est un habit usuellement masculin...

Comment: euh, pisser dans son froc ce peut être de rire (i' racontait tellement de c… que j'en ai pissé dans mon froc).